# Tuxguitar software and note length

Tags: guitar, arpeggios, tuxguitar

I am using Tuxguitar for guitar and how can I have for example (4/4) with the bass (E for example) ringing all the first bar while followed by 7 "eight notes"? It's quite often to face this issue when studying arpeggios!

Answer (score 3):

What you want there is having two Voices, which you can apparently do in TuxGuitar by Ctrl+1, Ctrl+2.

Answer (score 3):

Use "Let Ring" for the first note.
Right click on the first note, select Beat>Effect>Let Ring

[image: Let ring]